# Empty tensor issue when training a CNN using a google colab GPU

Tags: python, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I'm training a CNN to recognize actions in videos and I'm trying to move my code into the Google Colab environment so I can take advantage of the free GPU they offer to train my model faster. My code runs completely fine when training on my local machine as well as when I use my CPU in Google Colab. The issue I'm having is when I switch over to the GPU and try running my code I get an *InvalidArgumentError* which I'm struggling to figure out how to fix.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import pathlib
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

# Parameters
FRAME_HEIGHT, FRAME_WIDTH = 128, 128
NUM_FRAMES = 16
BATCH_SIZE = 32
NUM_CLASSES = 65  # Adjust this based on the actual number of sports classes

# Directory where the UCF101 data is located
DATA_DIR = pathlib.Path("/content/drive/My Drive/FinalYrProject/UCF-101")

# Helper function to load a single video file
def load_video(path):
    video_frames = []
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path.numpy().decode())
    try:
        while True:
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if not ret:
                break
            frame = cv2.resize(frame, (FRAME_HEIGHT, FRAME_WIDTH))
            video_frames.append(frame)
    finally:
        cap.release()
    video_frames = select_frames(video_frames, NUM_FRAMES)
    video_frames = np.array(video_frames) / 255.0
    return video_frames.astype(np.float32)

# Function to select a fixed number of evenly spaced frames from the video
def select_frames(frames, num_frames):
    # Calculate the interval to sample frames at.
    interval = len(frames) / float(num_frames)
    # Collect the frames.
    selected_frames = []
    for i in range(num_frames):
        idx = int(i * interval)
        selected_frames.append(frames[idx])
    return np.array(selected_frames)


# Function to process video file paths
def process_path(file_path):
    label = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)[-2]
    label = class_name_to_index.lookup(label)
    label = tf.one_hot(label, NUM_CLASSES)
    return file_path, label

def load_and_process_video(file_path, label):
    video = tf.py_function(load_video, [file_path], tf.float32)
    video.set_shape((NUM_FRAMES, FRAME_HEIGHT, FRAME_WIDTH, 3))
    return video, label

# Extract class names
class_names = np.array(sorted([item.name for item in DATA_DIR.glob('*/') if item.is_dir()]))
class_name_to_index = tf.lookup.StaticHashTable(
    initializer=tf.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(
        keys=tf.constant(class_names, dtype=tf.string),
        values=tf.range(tf.size(class_names), dtype=tf.int64)),
    default_value=-1)

# List of video file paths and their labels
video_files = list(DATA_DIR.glob('*/*.avi'))

# Shuffle video files
np.random.shuffle(video_files)

# Split into train and test sets
train_split = int(len(video_files) * 0.8)
train_files = video_files[:train_split]
test_files = video_files[train_split:]

# Create TensorFlow datasets
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([str(path) for path in train_files])
train_ds = train_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
train_ds = train_ds.cache().map(load_and_process_video, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
train_ds = train_ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

test_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([str(path) for path in test_files])
test_ds = test_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
test_ds = test_ds.cache().map(load_and_process_video, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
test_ds = test_ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

# Define the 3D ResNet model
def build_model(input_shape, num_classes):
    inputs = keras.Input(input_shape)
    x = layers.Conv3D(64, (7, 7, 7), strides=(2, 2, 2), padding="same")(inputs)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = layers.ReLU()(x)

    x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling3D()(x)
    x = layers.Dense(512, activation="relu")(x)
    outputs = layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax")(x)

    return keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

# Build and compile the model
model = build_model((NUM_FRAMES, FRAME_HEIGHT, FRAME_WIDTH, 3), NUM_CLASSES)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10, verbose=1, restore_best_weights=True)

# Train the model
history = model.fit(train_ds, epochs=100, validation_data=test_ds, callbacks=[early_stopping])

# Evaluate the model on the test set
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_ds)
print(f"Test accuracy: {test_acc}")

model.save("101Sports_classification_model.keras")
```

**ERROR**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-ca2e3895bb22> in <cell line: 62>()
     60 # Extract class names
     61 class_names = np.array(sorted([item.name for item in DATA_DIR.glob('*/') if item.is_dir()]))
---> 62 class_name_to_index = tf.lookup.StaticHashTable(
     63     initializer=tf.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(
     64         keys=tf.constant(class_names, dtype=tf.string),

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   5881 def raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name) -> NoReturn:
   5882   e.message += (" name: " + str(name if name is not None else ""))
-> 5883   raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   5884 
   5885 

InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__LookupTableImportV2_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} keys and values cannot be empty tensors. [Op:LookupTableImportV2] name:
```

I've searched online quite a bit and made sure that the GPU itself is properly initialized and available to me. I've also made sure there are no issues with the data itself. The error consistently says that *keys and values cannot be empty tensors.*, and no class names are saved which is confusing as when I run it with the CPU there are no issues with extracting and saving the class names.